# Windows 8.1 mixing PHP Storm, and Android Studio on the Task Bar

Tags: android-studio, windows-8.1, phpstorm

I have noticed that when I'm running Android Studio, and PhpStorm at the same time, Windows 8.1 will switch the preview of them on the task bar.

So when I mouse over Android Studio I see the project I'm working on in PhpStorm. When I mouse over PhpStorm, I see my Android Studio Project.

Is this a problem with Windows 8.1 or is it a problem with JetBrains?

Also is it something that I can fix on my own?

Comment: How are you launching these IDEs? Are you using the packaged .exe files or the .bat file?

Comment: I'm launching them using the standard .exe that they come with.  The only thing I did was mount them to the task bar.

Comment: It has to be JetBrain's issue -- the way how their app works/launches. Similar issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126488